# An automation to download a file to my laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I have some files I want to add to my laravel project on a regular basis say every hour

till now I had to download the file manually then move it to my laravel project
any particular thing I should look for to have this done?

Comment: Write a command that downloads whatever file you want to your project, [schedule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling) that command.

Comment: Are you having issue with your application downloading the file or triggering the download to happen automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the command to create a file, and download or email the file to the system or user. After that, you can run a cron job of this particular command. This will solve your issue